# How to change the on screen keyboard orientation?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

I recently install ubuntu developer preview 13.10 (saucy) onto Nexus 10. When i launch the terminal app i get the on-screen keyboard oriented in vertical direction  to the terminal and not horizontal. This make very difficult to type and see the terminal. For browser app it is oriented properly. Can somebody help me on how ubuntu-keyboard orientation can to made fixed or oriented properly with respect to typing.